# My jQueryMobile Datepicker works in google chrome but not on my phonegap mobile application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, datepicker, phonegap-plugins

I am currently trying to implement the jQueryMobile Datepicker (calbox) from http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/ into my phonegap mobile application for android.

The script tags which reference the various different jquery and jqueryMobile files located within my project look like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.comp.calbox"></script>
    <script src="js/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>
```

Then within a form tag within my html file I implemented the datepicker as follows:

```
<label for="mydate">Select Covering Date:</label>

<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "calShowWeek": true}'>
```

The datepicker works when I view the particular html file it is implemented in on Google Chrome, however when I run my project via my android device, the datepicker seems to operate as a textfield and no calendar is shown.
Any help in fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: possible for a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check the js loading order. First jQuery, jQueryMobile and then date-picker.

2) Looks like there are some duplicated js files included. For example jquery-1.7.1.min.js and query-1.10.2. Similary for jquery mobile.

Comment: I have tidyied up my js loading order and taken out all duplicate js files, however the datepicker is still not loading within the mobile application

Comment: Try to execute $("#mydate").trigger('change');